# At what point does $http trigger the digest cycle to start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My hypothesis is that it happens after the `.success` callback finishes executing. As opposed to

- Before the `.success` callback finishes running.
- Right after the request is sent out.

---

Consider this code:

**notes.service.js**

```
angular.module('notes').service('notes', ['$http', 
function($http) {
    var obj = {};

    this.getNotes = function() {
        $http.get('/notes').success(function(notesResponse) {
            obj.notes = notesResponse;
        });
        return obj;
    };
}]);
```

**notes.controller.js**

```
angular.module('notes').controller('NotesCtrl', ['notes', 
function(notes) {
    /* 
        $scope.$$watchers = [
            'notesCtrl.obj', cb
        ];
    */

    this.obj = notes.getNotes();    
}]);
```

**list.html**

```
<div class='page-header'>
    <h1>List of Notes</h1>
</div>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='note in notesCtrl.obj.notes track by note.id'>{{note | json}}</li>
</ul>
```

---

Imagine that the GET request takes an hour before it sends back a response.

- The service would send back `{}`.
- In the controller, `this.obj` would be set to `{}`.
- In the view, `notesCtrl.obj.notes` would be `undefined`, and thus the `ng-repeat` wouldn't happen.
- An hour later when the response comes back... it updates that object. The service points to it, the controller points to it and the view points to it. So they all get "updated" (it's really the object that gets updated; the pointers don't change, so they aren't really being "updated").
- The response triggers `.success`'s callback, which does the updating, and once `.success`'s callback finishes, a digest cycle is initiated.
- The digest cycle sees that `notesCtrl.obj` has changed, and thus runs the corresponding callback, which updates the DOM.

Is this correct?

Also, does `$http` trigger `$digest` or `$apply`? If it triggers `$digest`, how does it know which `$scope` to call it on? For example, the `$http` in the service isn't associated with a `$scope` (is it?).

Comment: Facing a similar issue. After making $hhtp call and updating the original object, the view bound to it gets updated, however the original object property somehow again is undefined at the end. Can someone suggest something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's amost correct: the success callback is in fact called *during* the digest cycle. You can see this if you try the following

```
$http.get('test.json').success(function(result) {
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Then (assuming the GET to `test.json` is a success), Angular will throw an error that can be seen in the console:

```
 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/wj4z1hDRXtK2GJnrkKuV?p=preview

> Also, does $http trigger $digest or $apply?

`$apply`, as it indeed doesn't know which scopes need to be checked, it triggers a global digest to check them all.

Comment: So just to confirm - in the case where the HTTP response takes an hour to come back, a $digest is triggered once it comes back to updated the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#id=LC1083)(Line:1083) of $http 
Find this line below

> /**
>          * Callback registered to $httpBackend():
>          *  - caches the response if desired
>          *  - resolves the raw $http promise
>          *  - calls $apply
>          */

It says callback is registered to $httpBackend() which do the following things in the order cache the response if desired(depending on you provide true in $http and it will cache it).Then it resolves the $httppromise which  means call  to success or error (it can also be then()) depending on the response.Then it finally call $apply for digest cycle.

And as far as i come to know from documentation $http service bind with  $rootScope.

And if you are thinking then how inside sucess $apply is throwing an error if $apply is starting after it then the answer is in doc itself $rootScope.$applyAsync which is running always and resolve the httppromise and then then after this $rootScope.$apply() runs.(Line:1102-1106)

Hope this clears your doubt.